# How to display fragments from navigation drawer?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am having trouble finding a question that uses this specific AUTO generated code from Android Studio. 
I am trying to figure out how to display a layout that I have when a button is clicked from the navigation drawer?

Here is the generated MainActivity

```
    package com.oxinc.android.classaverage;

    import android.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction("Action", null).show();
                }
            });

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
            toggle.syncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
            int id = item.getItemId();

//This is the part I am having trouble with

            if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
                // Handle the camera action
            } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {


            } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

            } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {
                //This is what I have come up with
                setContentView(R.layout.MyLayout)
            }

            DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would recommend you start at the basics of how to load a Fragment into an Activity because that is your real question. The NavigationView template is a bunch of boilerplate code that you really don't even need.

Comment: Secondly... `setContentView(R.layout.MyLayout)` is **not** correct unless you want to completely lose the NavigationView

Comment: Yeah I figured that as it crashed as I clicked on that view. Can you just give me an example of a couple lines on how to set a fragment in place of that code (setContentView.....)

Comment: I could, but [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Transactions) does it more justice than a few lines of code. Similarly, there is a [whole tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) on the navigation drawer pattern.

Comment: Okay thanks for the resources

Comment: Personally, I find CodePath's [tutorials](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer) fairly complete as well. Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

To display an fragment you newd at least an contai er!Do next.Let your android studio default class inherit FragmentActivity,change them accordingly or you could skip this though.Put an FrameLayout inside your root view where actually the content is put (android studio created that for you by default with drawer)And nust get an instance to that FrameLayout.Create an class lets say MyFragmenNumberOne.class and let it inherit FRAGMENT and be sure to use v4 as targeting support of older ones as weel.After which you simply will call patter code from fragmentManager for adding/removig/replacing fragments where you will pass your fragment class and container frame layout instances thats it.Important to mention that while calling beginTransaction.replace() the first parameter will tkae not view of your container but the resource id of it like R.id.myContainer and the second argument is the instance of fragment which either can be straight initialized with new keyword or have an static newInstance() method inside fragment class which will create an instance once and use it during app lifrcycle and that is better practise.Hopr i helped you anyhow.

Comment: Could you possibly include a code sample , it is a little hard to follow you. Thanks

Comment: Please take the time to format your answers better and spellcheck. This long paragraph is very hard to read